# How can I make my ball gradually increase in speed overtime?

Tags: swift, physics, gravity

I have currently set the gravity which makes the ball fall at a certain rate. I do not know however how to make the gravity gradually increase over time, hence making the ball drop faster. Each time the ball falls a point is gained so it would be good to increase the gravity for every 5 points or so. My current code is:

```
func setupPhysics() {
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -7.5)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
```

Just wondering if there is an easy way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you just increase the gravity value, when ever points is increased?

Comment: I understand that this is how I would do it. Increasing gravity when points are increased. Im new to this and need someone to point me in the right direction :/ I don't know how to do that.

Comment: show the whole code. Where are you setting the points. How is it increased?

Comment: "is an easy way to do this" is a matter of opinion. How do we know what's easy for you? This is not a well-formed question.

Comment: In any other programming language (e.g. I don't speak Swift) you could either do `physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: some_variable_tracking_gravity)` or `phyysicsWorld.gravity.dy += 1` (or something. Again, I don't speak Swift.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info you provided this would be a way to adjust gravity when points are set

```
var points: Double = 0 {
    didSet { 
        if points % 5 == 0 { // on fives 0, 5, 10, 15 etc            
            physicsWorld.gravity.dy -= 5 // will reduce gravity even further when ever points is set
        }
    }
}
```